# C Basic Sort Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'm not really understanding the process behind this basic sorting algorithm using nested For loops:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        for(j=i; j<MAX; j++){
            if(data[i] > data[j]){
                tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

If `j=i` then wouldn't it just be looping and comparing the same numbers seeing as i and j both start at 0 in the loops?

I've tried googling for an explanation on this particular bit of code and can't find anything useful.

Full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    int data[MAX];
    int i, j, tmp;

    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        for(j=i; j<MAX; j++){
            if(data[i] > data[j]){
                tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSorted List:\n");
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        printf("Item %d: %d\n", i, data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get this code? It appears as though someone couldn't decide between selection sort and bubble sort, then ended up with a bastardized version that is worse than both.

Comment: I've been following C tutorials on Youtube and this particular code was from this video: https://youtu.be/Dtbqs0M-B-s?t=19m9s

Comment: Yeah, it is an OK algorithm in the context of that exercise, but please do not use it elsewhere ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is a dummified [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) - it matches the description of selection sort on Wikipedia:

> The algorithm divides the input list into two parts: the sublist of items already sorted, which is built up from left to right at the front (left) of the list, and the sublist of items remaining to be sorted that occupy the rest of the list. Initially, the sorted sublist is empty and the unsorted sublist is the entire input list. The algorithm proceeds by finding the smallest (or largest, depending on sorting order) element in the unsorted sublist, exchanging (swapping) it with the leftmost unsorted element (putting it in sorted order), and moving the sublist boundaries one element to the right.

But indeed not the pseudo algorithm in that it does some unnecessary swaps.

In the first inner round, with `i` being equal to `j`, the comparison `data[i] > data[j]` will be false, and the swap will not be executed.

Then, `j` will be incremented, and now it is comparing `i`th value with `i + 1`th value.

To avoid one futile comparison, initialize `j` with `i + 1`:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < MAX; j++) {
        if (data[i] > data[j]) {
            tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

What it does different from ordinary selection sort is that it makes unnecessary swaps back and forth from the `i`th place. The ordinary selection sort finds the minimum index and does only one swap for each element:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    int min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < MAX; j++) {
        if (data[min] > data[j]) {
            min = j;
        }
    }

    tmp = data[min];
    data[min] = data[i];
    data[i] = tmp;
}
```

Nevertheless, the original matches the description of selection sort (and the running time is the same, though constants are worse due to unnecessary swapping) in that:

> The algorithm proceeds by finding the smallest (or largest, depending on sorting order) element in the unsorted sublist, exchanging (swapping) it with the leftmost unsorted element (putting it in sorted order)

is realized as *the algorithm finds the smallest element in the unsorted sublist, exchanging the current smallest item with the leftmost unsorted item as it goes over the list*.

---

The C standard library already contains [`qsort`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2) which can be used instead of reinventing the wheel - we just need to write the comparison function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_ints(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    return (*(const int*)a - *(const int*)b);
}

int main(void) {
    ...
    qsort(data, MAX, sizeof(int), compare_ints);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not selection sort. The OPs code doesn't match the pseudo on wikipedia, for one

Comment: @StoryTeller true, but it isn't bubblesort either. This is a selectionsort with unnecessary swapping, so the i value is swapped back and forth - if one keeps track of the smallest value instead then this will have much less swaps.

Comment: Better. Much better.

Answer (score 1):

No it wouldn't loop because you'll just swap the `data[i]` with `data[i]` twice although it is better to rewrite this piece of code like this :

```
for(i=0; i<MAX-1; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<MAX; j++){
        if(data[i] > data[j]){
            tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

but this two code are same.

the algorithm that this codes are using is [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). If you want to have better understanding of what it does take a look at the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). The gist of it is that it swaps any two adjacent values that it finds out of order, until all of the values are in order.

Comment: this isn't bubble sort.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - It is bubble sort, as evident by swapping immediately.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is selection sort with unnecessary swapping, but not bubblesort. Bubblesort always compares adjacent elements only.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - It's a bubblesort without an early halting flag. Inefficient, but bubblesort nonetheless.

Comment: @StoryTeller Bubblesort: "compares each pair of adjacent items and swaps them if they are in the wrong order". No, it is not. These facts are not up for discussion. I am right, you are wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I may be wrong, but you are most certainly not right. Selection Sort: "Selecting the lowest element requires scanning all n elements (this takes n − 1 comparisons) and then swapping it into the first position". The code in the OP does nothing of the sort.

Comment: @StoryTeller `for(j=i; j<MAX; j++)` there is your n-1, and it does n-1 comparisons. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        for(j=i; j<MAX; j++){
            if(data[i] > data[j]){
                tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Will clearly not work as it is supposed to. It basically needs to compare each and every element of the array and sorts them. Basically a bubble sort with time complexity O(n^2).

Rather than j=i

It should be j=i+1